# The second .click() function is not working

Tags: jquery

The first .click function is used to add an element(div) in a container and the second one is used to remove it from the container. The container initially has no elements. The removing of the function by clicking on it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function(){
       //Code for adding element to the container and 
       // removing class1 from it and adding class2

    });

    $(".class2").click(function(){
       alert("hi");   //Even the alert is not displayed
       $(this).fadeOut(100);    
    });
});
```

However, it works if the element is already there before the page loads in the container.
Any reasons why? Is it because of document.ready function? Solutions?

Comment: When you add event to `.class2` element, does your element exist already?

Comment: You need to set event handler to the element after adding that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because when you're adding the click handler for `.class2` elements, you're only adding the event to elements which have that class **at that specific moment in time**; e.g none.

Instead, you need to use event delegation like so;

```
$(document).on('click', '.class2', function () {
    alert('hi');
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

This will work as it binds an event to `document` (which always exists), which listens for clicks on any `.class2` elements using event delegation. For more info, read the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) documentation.

Comment: chrome block this script

Comment: @mohsen: I would double check that. The code is nothing uncommon. It'd be extremely weird for Chrome to block it.

Comment: i use .on function to change dynamically hyperlink link, but chrome blocked my second changes on hyperlink. (by the way, hyperlink contain (java:win.open....) but no problem in first link, second dynamically change by .on blocked by all browser)

Comment: Not blocked by Chrome for me.

Answer (score 3):

use delegate event handler for both classes(if you toggle between both of them, or if you not back to `class1` then second one is enough ) because after changing `class` elements are treated as dynamic.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".class1", function(){

});

$("#container").on("click", ".class2", function(){

});
```

Here `#container` refers to the parent of those class, you may have something else.

Answer (score 1):

As you try to add the code to click `.class2` it isn't yet created as i understand.
try adding the click event, after you created the `.class2` element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function(){
            //Code for adding element to the container and removing class1 from it and adding class2

        $(".class2").click(function(){
            alert("hi");         //Even the alert is not displayed
            $(this).fadeOut(100);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That will add an event handler to the existing `.class2` elements as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your answer is the proper one. Thanks: I didn't know about delegation in jquery!

Answer (score 0):

The events cannot be cast on elements that are not there when the function is elaborated. But, you could create a wrapper element (div) around "class1" and "class2", like this:

```
<div id="class1_wrapper">
  <span class="class1">
</div>
```

I used "span" for class1, because i don't know which element it is. Then, instead of the click event, you could use "on()":

```
 $("#class1_wrapper").on("click", ".class1", function ()
 {
   //Code for adding element to the container and removing class1 from it and adding class2
 });
```

this way, even if class1 is not there (the same can be done for class2), the click event will run